# Changing the light switch

Tags: electrical

I am changing the light fixtures and I got stuck. The wires coming from the wall are Red (was connected at the bottom of old switch), Blue (was connected at the top) and Copper (was connected with a screw). The switch I now have is plastic and does not have a place to connect the copper wire. It also has 3 ports - L1, L2 and L. Which wire do I connect to which port?

Comment: All the switches I bought last 2 years had a tiny schematics either on the package, on the back of the plastic part of the switch, or both. Can you look if yours include such thing, and post a picture?

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the switch?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like a 3 way switch but I don’t think I have seen one labeled that way.  Other than the copper you only had 2 wires I think , I would connect 1 to L1 and the other to L  , I believe l is the common  for a 3 way and L1& L2 are for the travelers , but for a single switch we just don’t use L2 . The switch won’t have on and off embossed on it if this is the case.
A photo would clear things up or the model # of the switch but I believe using L & L1 will get it working.